# Azure external load balaner - Source IP security

Tags: azure

I have two VMs being load balanced by an external facing load balancer.  I am able to successfully connect to those VM's from the internet through that LB rule.

However, I want to restrict access to that load balancer's public IP address (or more precisely - to the VM's behind it) to a specific source network.  So that rather than the entire internet being able to access it, only specific public subnets could use it.

Looking in TCP connection tables on the VM's - it looks like the Azure LB is natting the source IP coming through it.  So, my NSG's on the VM guests cannot filter on "SourceIP = Desired Source".

Is there any way to do this in the Resource Manager version of Azure?

Answer (score 1):

The source port and address range are from the originating computer, not the load balancer.

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/#design-considerations (look under "Load Balancers")

> Similar to public facing load balancers, when you create NSGs to
>   filter traffic coming through an internal load balancer (ILB), you
>   need to understand that the source port and address range applied are
>   the ones from the computer originating the call, not the load
>   balancer. And the destination port and address range are related to
>   the computer receiving the traffic, not the load balancer.

I'm *guessing* it's using x-forwarded-for and that NSGs understand that. Connection tables don't. They're raw connections and as such show the NAT.

Comment: How to restrict the access of a Web UI to a single static source IP.

If I have deployed a WebApp on  multiple VM and have added a Load Balancer which is load balancing my request but I only want to give access to the WebApp if the source IP is the organization static ip